# Помогите с View

Tags: android

Я создал свой класс View и назвал LetterView .

В layout файле это очень просто добавляется в RelativeLayout

Но проблема в том, что я должен добавить в java с нужным размером, которое зависит от размера экрана используя addView по умолчанию марджины 0dp .

Я попробовал изменить марджины в методах `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, но когда вызываю `getWidth()` , `getMeasuredWidth()` возвращает 0 . Позже попробовал в методе `onWindowFocusChanged()`, казалось бы все ок, но результат не удовлетворительный.Очень заметно как View изменяет марджины от 0 к нужному месту.

Если не понятно. Я создаю игру эрудит. И буквы должны находится в низу в от доски и каждая буква это View класс.

Я прошу у вас совета в каком методе расположить margin  LetterView  так, чтобы я знал длину и ширину экрана и расположил в нужном месте сразу же. Я почитал разные документации, но не могу добиться своего. 
Я почти закончил игру, но это калякса просто ужас.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `View`  есть метод `onMeasure(int, int)`, в нем ты можешь получить ширину и высоту методами `getMeasuredWidth()` и `getMeasuredHeight()`

Comment: Но мне нужно изменить маргины сразу после открытия активити . как и   где это сделать

Comment: в методе onCreate активити

Comment: у разного телефона разные длины и ширины . и как узнать это  в onCreate и располижить по центру например . если  в методе onCreate  там все 0 показывает .

Comment: В onCreate сооздавай и добавляй в активити любые вьюхи. Как добавишь - у них onMeasure вызовется, та-дам

Comment: Я все перепробовал, ничего не выходит.

Comment: Add view  в методе онСтарт, и изменяю маргины онвиндоус фокус чейнджед, как бы не заметно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать делать расчеты размеров в методе onLayout для вашей кастомной вьюшки, с последующим переопределением ее метода onDraw():

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    width = this.getWidth();     //определяем максимальные размеры вьюшки
    height = this.getHeight();
    //рассчитать нужные размеры startX, startY, mEndX, mEndY, исходя из
    //максимальных
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //mLetter - это, допустим, ImageView с буквой, которая хранится 
    //внутри вашей LetterView
    mLetter.setBounds(startX, startY, mEndX, mEndY);
    mLetter.draw(canvas);
}
```

Т.е. способ прорисовки кастомной вьюшки нужно определять в ее методе onDraw().